# How to make bash work with a TTY?

Tags: tty

`bash` works with STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. When `xterm` is opened,
it allocates the pseudo tty. Then xterm forks child process and STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR are tied to `slave_fd` via `dup2` and `exec` is called with `bash`. This is good.

But how to make `bash` work with TTY directly? How to make `bash` execute `open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR)`? So that I could attach a device to `/dev/ttyS0` and execute commands in `bash` from the device.

Comment: Take a look into the *agetty* utility. It handles the TTY stuff, then does a login or starts an alternative program.

Comment: @Janka I see - TTY is opened by a separate program. So, NO program is supposed to open a TTY directly? Only a dedicated program? The other way around: what if I have a program which does interaction via TTY by doing `open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR)` and sometimes I want to interact with the program via `xterm`, without changing the program itself - is this possible?

Comment: `exec 7<>/dev/ttyS0; stty <&7 [your stty settings]; cmd1 >&7; cmd2 <&7; cmd3 <&7 >&7 2>&1`. Setting the right modes & speed and using serial devices from the shell and parsing responses is tricky, though.

Comment: That comment would merit being turned into an answer, @UncleBilly.

Comment: What kind of a device is it? Is it a terminal and you want to log in _from_ it (have a shell listening to commands from the serial line); or is it something like a switch that provides its own console on the serial line and you want to connect _to_ it?

Comment: @ilkkachu It is a device which sends characters and reads characters, one by one. This device interfaces with self-made program on PC, which does `open` on the TTY. I asked this question because I was curious about general mechanisms how programs connect to TTY. As it turned out, as a rule an intermediate program is used for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the baud rate you can use screen to connect serial terminals like : `screen /dev/ttyS0 115200`

Comment: Can `screen` be used to connect to pseudo terminals? This does not work: `screen /dev/pts/X` (where `/dev/pts/X` was created by opening a new xterm window and issuing `kill -STOP $$` in it to prevent `bash` from messing with the tty but at the same time keep terminal window open to use the tty).